# Why did Einstein retain the hypothesis of length contraction?

Tags: special-relativity, relativity, history, aether

Why did Einstein retain the hypothesis of length contraction, which Lorentz introduced to save his æther theory, yet Einstein had no need to accept length contraction because he rejected the æther?

Comment: Length contraction is a consequence of the Lorentz Transform (and NOT a hypothesis), which Einstein definitely did NOT reject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't the aether that Einstein rejected, but the notion of absolute simultaneity; and this rejection was forced by taking the speed of light as constant from all inertial or stationary frames; and this is a deduction from Maxwells EM theory.

Lorentz, I take it, introduced length contraction as a way of making classical mechanics and EM consistent - or rather he suggested that making the two theories consonant with each other would force Lorentz contraction; and this move was accepted by Einstein.

Einstein however found a different and clearer physical basis to make the two theories consistent, from which he was able to deduce Lorentz contraction; in fact, the paper which introduces special relativity is named [the electrodynamics of moving bodies](http://hermes.ffn.ub.es/luisnavarro/nuevo_maletin/Einstein_1905_relativity.pdf) and begins:

> It is known that Maxwells electrodynamics - as usually understood at the present time - when applied to moving bodies, leads to asymmetries which are not inherent in the phenomena itself ...

This makes it quite clear he's thinking of both Maxwells and Newtons theory together, as was Lorentz.

Although its usually said that Einsteins theory rejected the aether, one might remark, that Einstein discovered that the aether was in part, spacetime; but equally, one might remark its not usually thought of in this fashion.

Comment: I'm not sure what this answer is supposed to be, but it reads as if it's the answer to something on [philosophy.SE]. It's not clear what references to Hegel or Aristotle have to do with the existence or non-existence of length contraction in special relativity.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: Ah, sorry; I though it was the philosophy site; I'll re-edit it.

Comment: When Einstein says "Maxwells electrodynamics—as usually understood at the present time", he means the incorrect interpretation he learned from Föppl (cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/264414/10024)). There are no "asymmetries which do not appear to be inherent in the phenomena" in Maxwell's theory.

Answer (score 2):

Ether theories did not yield consistent results, and they were not complying with experimental results. In this situation, Einstein presented a theory which allied the relativity principle with the postulate of the constancy of light.

The price for this solution (that nobody dared to pay before him) was the abandon of the absoluteness of simultaneity of events. He introduced time dilation.

Length contraction is nothing than a logical product of time dilation, and [length contraction can be derived from time dilation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction#Time_dilation)